# AndroidAnnotations: How to change layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-annotations

I have login- and game-layout in my activity. I would use AndroidAnnotations in my project, because that is cool! but I don't know, how to change correctly the login-layout to game-layout.

Initialization of login-layout I would do with the annotation:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.login)
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
```

May be that is a failure approche to change the layouts inside of activity? What is the clean way?

Comment: Hey mark, you should use the `[android-activity]` and `[android-layout]` tags instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... this is how android annotations is expected to be used. You don't have a syntax error, if that's what you are asking.

There's not much more I can do than to direct you to the installation page, which can be found below.

### [Eclipse Project Configuration](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Eclipse-Project-Configuration)

---

Just use two separate `Activity`s for the login and game. When the user logs in, you will launch the new Game activity with,

```
startActivity(this, GameActivity.class);
```

This is far preferred to remaining into the current activity and simply swapping the layouts in and out. An activity is supposed to be focused on a particular aspect that you are trying to achieve. The game and login are completely different in their functionality, so it definitely makes sense to separate their functionality into separate activitys.

Comment: I have no syntax error. The Question is: How to change Layout inside of MyActivity, from Login-Layout to Game-Layout.

Comment: If your game-layout is `R.id.game`, then you use `@EActivity(R.layout.game)`?

Comment: I would like to change it inside of lifecyle. If user is stored on, he change to game-layout, else to login-layout.

Comment: Shouldn't you separate those into separate activitys? i.e. the user is in the LoginActivity... then enters his login information... then if he enters his password incorrectly, a new GameActivity is launched?

Comment: Can you give me a small example or a link for such example. I thought that the correct way is to switch the layout with a call of `setContentView(...)` methode. You can edit your answear :)

Comment: You almost always should prefer creating new activitys instead of swapping in/out layouts with `setContentView`. Swapping in/out layouts will mean that your user won't be able to easily navigate your application as they would if you had started a new activity instead.